# How to capture database connection state or ping connection?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Using [MySql driver](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) for Node.js, here is my `ping` method:

```
function ping(){
  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return false;
    }

    console.log('connection authenticated: ' + (connection.state == "authenticated"));
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
  });

  console.log("connection: " + connection.state);
  return (connection.state == "authenticated");
}
```

Apparently, this node-mysql library does not have a native Ping method. I thought this would serve well in its stead. However, I am seeing the following issue in the console:

> debugger listening on port 53213
>   connection: disconnected
>   Fri, 26 Dec
>   2014 14:12:38 GMT RazorJS Express server listening on port 3000
>   connection authenticated: true
>   connected as id 17

It seems that the connection state is being logged and returning false before the connection is actually open. Maybe this is being executed async? How can I get this to function synchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written the below outside the callback on connection.connect function.So before your connection.connect executes its callback ,the below code gets executed(async nature of node.js) and therefore its first consoled as disconnected.

```
console.log("connection: " + connection.state);
  return (connection.state == "authenticated");
```

The above should be inside the callback.

```
    function ping() {
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            return false;
        }
        console.log('connection authenticated: ' + (connection.state == "authenticated"));
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
        console.log("connection: " + connection.state);
        return (connection.state == "authenticated");
    });
}
```

Comment: I get it now ...callbacks are how we handle returns from async methods.